# Docker postgres incompatible version

Tags: postgresql, docker

I did a system prune all in my docker containers. The problem is that when I made the docker compose up the postgres containers keep restarting due to this error:

`PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization activitiesdb  |  activitiesdb  | 2023-11-15 03:07:41.045 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server activitiesdb  | 2023-11-15 03:07:41.045 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 15, which is not compatible with this version 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1).`

Something i can't understand is why if in my local machine (replicating the error), I specify the postgres:15 when I compose up it works, but in the production server even if the docker compose is correct it doesn't it keeps showing the same error. If the problem has something to the with the volumes, I can't just delete them because they have sensitive data. In that case, how can I make a backup of each individual volume? Or is there another solution?

This is my docker compose reduced due to confidentiality, but with the same approach I have in my local machine:

```
volumes:
  db_quotes:   
    driver: local
  db_activities:   
    driver: local
    
 quotes-db:
    container_name: quotesdb
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./QuotesMicroservice/sql/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5480:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./QuotesMicroservice/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db_quotes:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
        - app-network

activities-db:
    container_name: activitiesdb
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB_NAME=activitiesdb
    ports:
        - '5433:5432'
    volumes: 
        - db_activities:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app-network
```

This is the same way I'm importing the rest of the postgres dbs

Comment: You must be doing something wrong on your production server if you try to run a postgres 15 container but "*it keeps showing the same error*", as that error specifically comes from "*version 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1)*". Show us how you are trying to run that container, we can't help you otherwise. As you demonstrated on your local machine, running postgres:15 is the correct approach.

Comment: @Bergi yes let me show you.

Comment: @Bergi i already edited the question.

Comment: What is `./QuotesMicroservice/sql/Dockerfile` doing? How are you using that compose file, what command are you using to start the container?

Comment: @Bergi thats building the postgres image with an initial seeding file. That’s the same way it is in my local Machine and it works.

Comment: Notice that `image: postgres:15` [is ignored due to the presence of `build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#definitions)

Comment: @Bergi Okay yes, but for example I just added another db. As you can see it is just build with the image and it is giving me the error in production and not in my local.

Comment: Does the new db use the same volume (or a new one), and still give that error? Hard to believe. But yeah, there must be some difference between your local machine and production, but we can't help you find it from the contents of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255945/discussion-between-la-bola-al-riel-and-bergi).

Comment: @Bergi it uses a new one. For each database it uses a different volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `quotes-db` custom image is overwriting the standard `postgres:15` image.  You don't show what's in its Dockerfile, but this seems likely to be the cause of the problem.

You should do two things:

1. `docker pull postgres:15` manually, so that you're sure you have the Docker Hub image locally.
2. In the `quotes-db` service, delete the `image:` line.

   ```yaml
   quotes-db:
     # image: postgres:15  # <-- delete
     build: ...
   ```

If you [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) an image, normally Compose picks the image name for you.  But if you also specify [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) then that specifies the name of the image that gets built.  It does *not* specify the base image but the result of the output.  Generally if you have `build:`, you should only specify `image:` if you're planning to `docker-compose push` the built image to a registry.

So what's happening here is that `quotes-db` is building its own PostgreSQL image, presumably getting the newer version of the database, but naming the custom image `postgres:15`.  `activities-db` then runs the image named `postgres:15`, but that's now the custom image and not the standard PostgreSQL image.

Comment: This solved it. I just can’t understand why in my local machine I solved it by just specifying the version and without pulling the Postgres version. But it worked.